# Delete Site from Archiv Widget

Tags: wordpress

I created a Page in WP and i found it in the Archiv-Widget.

Is there a way to create a Page and don't show it in the Archiv?

I use WP 3.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way of excluding items using the built-in archive widget, unfortunately.

Comment: I figured something like that :( So the codemonkey will work on it ;) thanks